# Set layout_anchor of FloatingActionButton to id of element from parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button

Its possible set `app:layout_anchor` of FloatingActionButton to id of element from parent layout?

**VIEW_A**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar">                  <--- APP_BAR
        ...
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout />                                 <--- VIEW_B

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**VIEW_B**

```
<LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
        ...
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar" />          <--- SET APP_BAR

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

No it is not. Simply do this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar">                  <--- APP_BAR
    ...
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout />                                 <--- VIEW_B

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar" />
```